# Using Java and Selenium, how can I select all the options in a dropdown?

Tags: java, selenium

I am new to Java and Selenium. I want to grab all the values in a dropdown, and make sure they match the expected values. So I wan't to make sure that the dropdown contains the values of A, B, and C.

```
<select id="ctl00_cphMainContent_dq14_response" name="ctl00$cphMainContent$dq14$response">
<option value="0" selected="selected">Please Select...</option>
<option value="253">DEP900</option>
<option value="252">DEP800</option>
<option value="251">DEP700</option>
<option value="250">DEP600</option>
<option value="248">DEP400</option>
<option value="247">DEP300</option>
<option value="246">DEP200</option>
<option value="245">DEP100</option>
<option value="249">DEP500</option>
<option value="254">DEP1000</option>
</select>
```

I can't figure out how to grab all the text values of the dropdown element (ex. DEP900). I want to put them in an ArrayList, and compare that to another list that contains the expected values. I was going to do that with Assert.assertEquals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to find the option elements (using `WebDriver#findElements`) and use `getText` to retrieve the inner text (e.g: DEP9000) or `getAttribute("value")` to retrieve it's value.

Example:

```
List<WebElement> options = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#ctl00_cphMainContent_dq14_response option"));

for(WebElement opt : options){
  opt.getText();
  opt.getAttribute("value");
}
```

Comment: Thanks Marlon. I'm still having trouble retrieving the text. I edited my original question.

Comment: This worked in retrieving the dropdown options. The error I had before was a typo.

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this :

```
    public void CompareTwoList(ArrayList<String> listfromUser)
{
   WebElement select =driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_cphMainContent_dq14_response"));
   List<WebElement> options=select.findElements(By.tagName("option"));
   ArrayList<String> listFromGUI=new ArrayList<>();

   // we are starting by 1 bcoz we are not storing the please select option in the list
   for(int i=1;i<options.size();i++)
   {
     String optionTemp=options.get(i).getText().trim();
     listFromGUI.add(optionTemp);
   }

  //first we will sort both the list so that both of them are sorted in the same order
  Collections.sort(listFromGUI,String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
  Collections.sort(listfromUser,String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);

  Assert.assertEquals(listfromUser,listFromGUI);


}
```

Comment: One thing that you can remove is sorting if both the list you have already sorted.